# Refile from one file to other

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to implement GTD in emacs based on http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/gtd_workflow.html and I have a problem with refiling.

In the file .emacs I have such a configuration

```
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
'(org-refile-targets (quote (("gtd.org" :maxlevel . 1) ("done.org" :level . 1))))
```

The sequence Cc Cw   can select only the place of the current file:

- gtd.org/
- gtd.org/tasks
- gtd.org/projects

Please help in determining why do not I move to done.org

Regards
Krzysiek

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a fix of your code:

```lisp
(setq org-refile-targets
      '(("gtd.org" :maxlevel . 1)
        ("done.org" :maxlevel . 1)))
```

Here's a setup similar to what I use now:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files
      '("gtd.org" "done.org"))

(setq org-refile-targets
      '((nil :maxlevel . 3)
        (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 3)))
```

This first element of `org-refile-targets` decides the heading levels to consider
within current file, the second element - within other agenda files.

Comment: Headings are transferred, but have a level 1. Can refiling set up so that the headers have the same level in the file done.org?

Comment: The heading level in `done.org` will be exactly the level of
the refile destination plus one. So if you want to change it, change
the level of the refile destination.

Comment: Now in my config I have
    (setq org-refile-targets
      '(("gtd.org" :maxlevel . 2)
        ("done.org" :maxlevel . 2)))
and after
    C-c C-w 
I only see
gtd.org/ and done.org. Transfered heading still have level 1.

Comment: All headings of level up to 2 should be available for selection as refile targets. Which one did you select?

Comment: When I comment
    (setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
and still have
    (setq org-refile-targets '(("gtd.org" :maxlevel . 2) ("done.org" :maxlevel . 2)))
it works just like you said. It seems to me that this situation has to do with the case described in the https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg12503.html

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @abo-abo your setup works well for me, but in order to narrow/filter the selection by the full path to the refile-targets, `(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'full-file-path)` needs to be added to the config file.